# Onclick function not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events

I have the following code
http://jsfiddle.net/6xcn6gzj/, I need to remove an element off the page using its attribute, so I opted for jQuery's remove. My problem is that once I click on the image, nothing happens. I tried calling the function from javascript itself and it was working perfectly. For some reason, the event is just not happening.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="whatever" alt="test" onclick="close('test')">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
console.log('hi');
function close(template) {
    console.log(template);
    $('body').find('img[alt="'+template+'"]').remove();
}
```

The console is logging "hi" which indicates that javascript is running fine but it never logs the template name. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two problems:

- Don't name your function `close`, that will conflict with `window.close`
- Your fiddle was set to load your code in the onload handler, so your function was local to that function. Change your fiddle to load the script in the `<head>` http://jsfiddle.net/6xcn6gzj/7/

```js
function doClose(template) {
  console.log(template);
  $('body').find('img[alt="' + template + '"]').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="whatever" alt="test" onclick="doClose('test')" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, perfect answer. I'll accept it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should just call this.remove()?

```
<div>
    <img src="whatever" alt="test" onclick="this.remove()">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6xcn6gzj/2/

Comment: This is not really an option for me because I need to remove more than one element with one click.